# UI-GRID Dynamic column headers and array of object data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have following data

```
vm.myData =
        {
            'Type' : 
            [
                'A',
                'B',
                'C'
            ],
            'Data': [
            {
                'Key': 'XXX',
                'AValues':
                {
                    'ID': '1',
                    'Val': '10'
                },
                'BValues':
                {
                    'ID': '2',
                    'Val': '20'
                },
                'CValues':
                {
                    'ID': '2',
                    'Val': '20'
                }
            },
            {
                'Key': 'TTT',
                'AValues':
                {
                    'ID': '2',
                    'Val': '30'
                },
                'BValues':
                {
                    'ID': '4',
                    'Val': '70'
                },
                'CValues':
                {
                    'ID': '2',
                    'Val': '20'
                }
            }
            ]
        };
```

I am trying to show data as below

```
Key A   B   C
XXX 10  20  20
TTT 30  70  20
```

I tried it many ways but not able to get desired result.
I want the name of the Columns to come from 'Type' on 'myData'.
I am able to display first row by hardcoding.

```
vm.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: [
                { name: 'Key', field: 'Data[0].Key'},
                { name: 'A', field: 'Data[0].AValues.Val'},
                { name: 'B', field: 'Data[0].BValues.Val'},
                { name: 'C', field: 'Data[0].CValues.Val'}
            ],
            data: vm.myData
        };
```

I would really appreciate any help.

***Update***
After going through Naren Mulrali's suggestion, I did following which gives me desired result.
But I have hardcoded column names(I need different display names).
Is there a way to dynamically get column header from the 'Type' array from 'myData'

```
vm.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: [
                { displayName: 'Key', name: 'Key' },
                { displayName: 'A', name: 'AValues.Val' },
                { displayName: 'B', name: 'BValues.Val' },
                { displayName: 'C', name: 'CValues.Val' }
            ],
            data: vm.myData.Data
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your Object into a format that angular ui grid understands, please refer to the below JSFiddle

```
        angular.forEach($scope.myData.Data, function(value, index){
          value.AValues = value.AValues.Val;
          value.BValues = value.BValues.Val;
          value.CValues = value.CValues.Val;
          $scope.myData.Data[index] = value;
        });
```

JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/6bv0geax/)

Comment: I got the desired result after looking at your suggestion. This does not change the data. I have updated my question.

Comment: @user2769614 I understand what you mean, you want the column defs to get generated dynamically, but one question, do we need to use vm.myData.Type array for this, if so why is key not present in this array?

Comment: Key is static column name, A, B, C are dynamic column names, I might want column D in future, that is why I am trying to avoid hard coding, another way I see is just have the json send 'A' instead of 'AValues' and my column name would be 'A'.

Comment: @user2769614 If the second option is doable then go for the second option, because the code in the above plunkr does not require columnDefs, if you find this difficult then a for loop is needed to generate the column defs, which is also fine, but you are saying something about static and dynamic columns, which doesn't seem like a good approach.

Comment: The solution I used is in my question itself under Update section, marking this as an answer because it helped me get exact code I want.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. I have used this approach to populate the grid columns dynamically. I have another requirement to show the row value in checkbox like when the value comes as "Yes" then it should show checkbox with value checked. How to do this? Also I want to add one button against each row dynamically created? How to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1843970 Create a new question, with details about your issue.

Comment: I have created the question with the details :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703230/how-to-show-checkboxes-and-button-in-ui-grid-with-dynamic-columnheaders